# Programmatically launch a SearchView (Android)

Tags: android, searchview, android-searchmanager

I'm using a SearchView widget to perform a search which includes the query and some other information from CheckBoxes.

I followed the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) for using the SearchView widget and it works great - but because I have additional info to add to the search, I want to have a FloatingActionButton trigger the search.

My code so far for setting up the search

```
private void setUpSearchCard(View layout) {
    // Retrieve SearchManager and the SearchView
    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getContext()
            .getSystemService((Context.SEARCH_SERVICE));
    mSearchView = (SearchView) layout.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    // Direct the SearchView to the activity that will get the result
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(
            new ComponentName(getContext(), SwipeDeckActivity.class)
    ));

    // Expand the bar by default
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}
```

What I wish to add to this function is something like this

```
    // Set up the search fab
    mSearchFAB = (FloatingActionButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fab_search_button);
    mSearchFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mSearchView.launchSearch();
        }
    });
```

How can I do that? (Obviously the query that was inserted should be sent)

P.S. I do not want to use the Android supplied button that pops on the SearchView

Comment: just try mSearchView.PerformClick() and give a try? am not sure just give it a try.

Comment: Nope, it clicks the SearchView and sets the focus to it, to initiate it you must press "Enter" key while on SearchView :/

Comment: if i am understanding it right you are trying to do the search operation not the searchView focusing?

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Exactly, I want to have like a "form" with a SearchView, and checkboxes, then I will press a FAB I create and launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But I just was looking for something similar.

Try the following code snippet,

```
mSearchView.setQuery()
```

Maybe this helps someone.